# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" when using jQuery/SVG plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying out Keith Wood's [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) plugin to manipulate SVG via JavaScript, as suggested on another thread. The plugin sources include a sample SVG picture of a lion. I'm trying to load the lion picutre onto a page, using the syntax from the documentation: `$(selector).svg({loadURL: 'lion.svg'});` -- in my case, the `div` I'm trying to load into is id'ed as `'map'`, so the snippet I'm using is `$('#map').svg({loadURL: 'lion.svg'});`. Anyway, when I load my page, I get this error in the JS console: `jquery.svg.js:1341 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. **Is this a bug in the source code or am I doing something wrong here?**

Here is the pertinent section of the jquery.svg.js code:

```
/** Attach the SVG functionality to a jQuery selection.
@param [command] {string} The command to run.
@param [options] {object} The new settings to use for these SVG instances.
@return {jQuery} For chaining further calls. */
$.fn.svg = function(options) {
var otherArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
if (typeof options === 'string' && options === 'get') {
    return $.svg['_' + options + 'SVG'].apply($.svg, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs));
}
return this.each(function() {
    if (typeof options === 'string') {
        $.svg['_' + options + 'SVG'].apply($.svg, [this].concat(otherArgs));
    }
    else {
        $.svg._attachSVG(this, options || {});
    } 
});
};
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04.